# How to add class on a button click in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a form with fields which are disabled by default. User can only view the info in it unless they press the edit button. when they click the edit button the fields will be re enable the fields with some new styles(say a green border) i want to add a class to these field which i can style in my CSS. What is the Angular way to do it?

HTML

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="edit_setting()" ng-controller="ExchangeController">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name" ng-disabled="true">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" required ng-disabled="true">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Controller

```
  function ExchangeController($scope) {
      var details = "https://pvbp.com/api/settings.html?contactid=292351&exchange_id=7124&clearinghouseid=1&token=e5349652507c0esae86d50fdbdc53222cf97&page=view";
      $http.get(details).success(function(response){
          $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_name = response.name;
          $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_host_name = response.email;   
      });

      $scope.edit_exchange_setting_click = (function(){
        // add new class for the fields here dynamically        
      });
  }
```

Comment: Have you considered using ng-class?

Comment: I already have class for my text fields. is it possible to add an extra class along with it using ng-Class? @Sphaso

Comment: yes, `ng-class` will not remove your existing class

Comment: You can use conditional statements inside ng-class to toggle one class or the other.

Comment: Suppose if i want to add a class 'test' to the fields of my form along with the existing class. how do i do that using ng-class when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ngClass` directive for that ([documentation of ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass))

If you want to add, let's say, green borders to your `input` element *when the form is in the editable state*, you will use `ngClass` as the following :

```
<input type="text" ng-class="{'greenBorder': editable}" ng-model="name" />
```

This will add the `greenBorder` css class only if the boolean variable `editable` is truthy. I simply defined `greenBorder` for the example as follows :

```
.greenBorder {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Note that `ngClass` will not remove your existing classes, if any, added with `class="..."`. It will just append or not the class `greenBorder` to them. Therefore, there is absolutely no problem if you have a `form-control` or any other class added statically.

You can see [a demo of that in action](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/Lo5d3oe2/1/)